# Trouble returning wms tile in Cesium, from geoserver, vnd.ogc.se_xml

Tags: geoserver, wms, cesium

I am running Cesium in sandbox, and trying to access wms layers from geoserver I am running locally on a virtual machine but having trouble returning the wms data.

The request hits the tile image, but I think nothing is being returned, or there is some issue with processing the data on the way back when trying to be processed in Cesium.

ex: the request url: https://192.168.99.100/geoserver/geonode/wms?version=1.1.0&service=WMS&request=GetMap&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&layers=ne_50m_admin_0_countries&srs=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=-180%2C0%2C-90%2C90&width=256&height=256

reaches an image/tile:
[image]

- the response headers:
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Type:application/vnd.ogc.se_xml;charset=UTF-8
  Date:Mon, 10 Aug 2015 19:46:08 GMT
  Server:nginx
  Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
  Transfer-Encoding:chunked
  X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
  X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

how do i interpret the type: vnd.ogc.se_xml ?

- the errors are: An error occurred in "WebMapServiceImageryProvider": Failed to obtain image tile X: N Y: N Level: N.
- The relevant code is as follows:

  var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

  var provider = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
  url: 'url_to_wms_server',
  layers : 'layer_name'
  });
  viewer.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(provider);

any idea what's going wrong or what to change?

also, when i change the version to 1.3.0, the response type is text/xml but the url does not hit an image when i check.

Comment: About how to interpret the MIME type, it is written into WMS 1.1.0 standard as `Service Exception Report XML shall be valid according to the Service Exception DTD in Annex A.3. In an HTTP environment, the MIME type of the returned XML shall be "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml".`

Comment: When you switch to version 1.3.0, you'll need to change `srs=epsg:4326&` to `crs=CRS:84&`, for your map to work in Cesium

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [WMS Spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms) you will see how to set the format of the error messages that the server sends you.

In this case it is clearly saying that the number `256:` is invalid. Somewhere you are sending a request with that number in it, check the URL. For more information turn up the logging verbosity in GeoServer and it will send you back more details, or you could look in the log file to see what is going wrong there.

Comment: 256 and 256 are the default parameters -set by cesium - of the height and width of the tile.  those parameters and url provided go to the tile image, which is 256x256.  I don't see what could be wrong with those numbers especially since the url goes to the tile image.
see the documentation for WebMapServiceImageryProvider, which is the function that is being used and sets those parameters.
https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/WebMapServiceImageryProvider.html

thoughts?

Comment: but your 256 has a **:** on the end

Comment: is that not just the formatting of the error message?

Comment: No that is the error message - that's why GeoServer put quotes around it

Comment: I've cleaned up your formatting to help clarify this

Comment: but the url (which has the input parameters) doesn't have the colon in it, and i get the same issue when i explicitly identify the h/w parameters.  How can this colon be added or how can i prevent it from being added?

Comment: You'll need to add more information about your cesium setup - especially if it works for some tiles and not others. Have you looked in the GeoServer log?

Comment: all the requests successfully reach a tile. but the issue is nothing coming back to display on Cesium.  I am just running on sandcastle with the code provided

Comment: either your request returns a tile (an image) or an error (as above) if some work and others don't then you have a problem with your layer. If they all fail you have a problem with ceasium

Comment: I believe that xml script was a response for something i was testing so I don't think it was relevant.  And Yes, I think there is an issue with Cesium processing the tile because the tile exists (see the edited post).  but what are the options for debugging so i can figure out why cesium is having trouble processing tiles. thanks for the help btw